# SWT Window doesn't close on context menu click

Tags: java, events, swt, contextmenu

I am using

```
Shell shell = new Shell(display,SWT.NONE);
```

This however removes the listener or disables the close event. So when I try to right click the application in the taskbar and say "Close window" it doesn't do anything. If I use another shell style such as

> SWT.MIN

then it performs the close operation. I am using windows 7.

I need to have a borderless window and at the same time be able to close the application from the context menu, if that is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SWT.NO_TRIM
```

does exactly what you want. A window without border that still closes using the taskbar context menu.